# Green Screen when the system restarts

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting, maintenance

I am having this problem with the Sony Laptop (VGN-NR38Z series). Sometime, it just crashes with a green screen.

When I do a hard reboot, it will have a Green Stripes in the boot menu as well.

Any idea, what could be wrong. I am sorry, this is the only information I can give you at the moment. And it is not specific to Windows or Ubuntu since I noticed this in both.

Thanks,
Kiran

Comment: Without more info, it sounds like a video problem. Do you see it when using an external monitor?

Comment: Yes, I have connected a external monitor via a VGA cable.

Comment: Sounds like the video adaptor in the laptop has developed a fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing that this happens with an external display, this definitely sounds like a problem with your video card.

Most likely, the easiest fix is to take it to a repair shop to replace/repair the video card.

If you'd rather try and fix it at home, I would first try to take apart the laptop, remove the heatsink from the graphics card, reapply thermal grease, blow any dust out, and put the heatsink/fan back on.

Comment: Thanks.. I will have a look. Thanks for your quick response.